# Getting results from the db when polymorphic and many-to-many relations are involved in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my app, a Bookmark can belong to one User and many Collections; a Collection can belong to one User and many Bookmarks; and a Bookmark can morph into a Post, which is in turn a morphable model. Here are my relations:

```
class Bookmark {
    public function bookmarkable(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function collections() {
        return $this->belongsToMany( Collection::class, 'bookmark_collection', 'bookmark_id', 'collection_id' )->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo( User::class );
    }
}

class Collection {
    public function bookmarks() {
        return $this->belongsToMany( Bookmark::class, 'bookmark_collection', 'collection_id', 'bookmark_id' )->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo( User::class );
    }
}

class Post {
    public function bookmark(): MorphOne
    {
        return $this->morphOne( Bookmark::class );
    }

    public function postable(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Here are my tables (relevant fields only):

```
users
- id

bookmarks
- id
- bookmarkable_id
- bookmarkable_type
- user_id

collections
- id
- user_id

bookmark_collection
- bookmark_id
- collection_id
- created_at

posts
- id
```

My question is, how can I get all the bookmarked posts that were added to a specific viewlist? My current solution is:

```
$collections->bookmarks()->with('bookmarkable')->get()->pluck('bookmarkable');
```

but I don't like it at all and creates some issues with pagination. I'm looking for a solution that gets the posts directly, without getting the bookmark models (which I don't need). As I said, the solution should work well with pagination and I should be able to order the results by the `created_at` field in the `bookmark_viewlist` table.

On the other hand, I managed to get all the posts bookmarked by a user directly (without getting the bookmark models) with this code:

```
class User {
    public function bookmarkedPosts() {
        return $this
            ->hasManyThrough(
                Post:class,
                Bookmark::class,
                'user_id',
                'id',
                'id',
                'bookmarkable_id'
            )
            ->where( 'markable_type', Post::class )
            ->orderByDesc(
                Bookmark::select('created_at')
                    ->whereColumn( 'bookmarks.markable_id', 'posts.id' )
                    ->orderByDesc('created_at')
                    ->limit(1)
            );
    }
}
```

but I'm happy to hear ideas if it can be improved.

So to recap, two questions:

1. How do I get all bookmarked posts in a specific viewlists without getting the bookmark models, and in a way that I can paginate the results by the `created_at` field of the `bookmark_viewlist` table?
2. Can the `bookmarkedPosts` method on the User class be improved?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the collection is the collection for the user, right?

I guess you could do this:

```
$collection = Collection::find($collectionId);
$bookmarkedPosts = $collection->bookmarkedPosts()->paginate(10);// or paginate($pageSize)


class Collection {
    public function bookmarkedPosts() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            Post::class,
            Bookmark::class,
            'collection_id',  // this is the foreign key in bookmark_collection table
            'id',             // this is the id from collections table, we match that to the collection_id
            'id',             // this is the bookmark_id
            'bookmarkable_id'
        )->where('bookmarkable_type', Post::class)
         ->orderBy('bookmark_collection.created_at');  // table_name.created_at for proper order by
    }
}
```

Also, is the Collection model a must? You can also remove the Collection and simply join bookmarks to user and then use something like:

```
class Bookmark {
    public function bookmarkable(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}

class Post {
    public function bookmark(): MorphOne
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Bookmark::class);
    }

    public function postable(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class User {
    public function bookmarks() {
        return $this->hasMany(Bookmark::class);
    }
}

// Usage:
$user = User::find($user_id);

if ($user) {
    $pageSize = 10;
    $bookmarkedPosts = $user->bookmarks()
        ->where('bookmarkable_type', Post::class)
        ->with('bookmarkable')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->paginate($pageSize);

    // this query will return all bookmarked posts for the user specified
} else {
    // some message about not getting the posts or handle different types of errors, infos etc.
}
```

You can return the posts in json like this:

```
return response()->json(['bookmarked_posts' => $bookmarkedPosts]);
```

Or some error or info:

```
return response()->json(['error' => 'User not found'], 404);
```